# Why does CGAffineTransformMakeRotation not work in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I found that when I use CGAffineTransformMakeRotation to rotate the line, the line is not changed.

This is my code:

```
func drawLine(drawObj:DrawObj) {
        var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSaveGState(context);

        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, drawObj.drawPara.lineColor.CGColor)
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, drawObj.drawPara.fillColor.CGColor)
        let originX = drawObj.left - drawObj.currentWidth/2
        let originY = drawObj.top - drawObj.currentHeight/2
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, originX, originY);
        let toX = originX + drawObj.currentWidth
        let toY = originY + drawObj.currentHeight
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, toX, toY);

        CGContextStrokePath(context);
        let roation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(Double(drawObj.angle)*M_PI/(180)))
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, roation)
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you rotated the context after you drew the line. If you want the rotation to apply to the line, rotate the context first. Once the line is drawn, it's drawn.